# Why Num can be treated as Floating in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, subclass, class-hierarchy, adhoc-polymorphism

I defined a function that computes `sqrt` and converts argument from and to `Integral` class:

```haskell
isqrt :: Integral i => i -> i
isqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral
```

I don't understand why that compiles. If we write out signatures of the individual functions we get:

```haskell
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

So "`sqrt`" takes something of `Floating` type but it is supplied with `Num`. If you take a look at class [hierarchy](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/File:HaskellClasses.svg), you can see that `Floating` "inherits" from `Num` but not the other way around. I would understand if `Floating` could be implicitly treated as `Num` because it is a more "specialized" type. Why this is OK for the compiler ?

Comment: There is another interesting question: what type of value will be consumed by `sqrt`? `Floating` is just type class (collection of some types). You can try answer.

Comment: I can't be sure since I don't know how `fromIntegral` works internally. We started with `Integral` so value could be `Int` or `Integer` and `Floating` can be `Float` or `Double`. Maybe the types of values are mapped respectively `Int` -> `Float` and `Integer` -> `Double` according to their max size ? That would make sense.

Comment: No, `fromIntegral` can map `Int -> Float`, `Int -> Double`, `Integer -> Float`, `Integer -> Double`, `Integer -> Int`, `Int -> Integer` etc. So it can map any integral type to any number (which maybe intergral or some else).

Comment: I understand but I took into account that `sqrt` takes `Floating` type class. So what type of value will be consumed by `sqrt` and how it is determined ?

Comment: Basically, in this case compiler should throw error that there is ambiguity. But there is the Haskell feature named default instance which resolves it. You can read [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4) about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `sqrt` is *not* supplied with *any `Num`.*

Its supplier `fromIntegral` is *able* to *produce* any `Num` as needed indeed, whereas `sqrt` demands a *`Floating`* as its input. And `Floating` *is* a *subclass* of `Num`.

So `fromIntegral` happily obliges. Since it can produce any `Num`, surely it can produce any type in any subclass of `Num`. So whatever the specific concrete type it ends up to be, it is in `Floating`, and thus necessarily it is in `Num`.

Thus `fromIntegral` has no problem  providing it.

*edit:* `Floating` is not a type. It is a class of types. A concrete type might be in `Floating` class of types. Since `Floating` is a subclass of `Num`, such type is also guaranteed to be in `Num`. It is not something that happens automatically due to "inheritance" that you mention. That "inheritance" i.e. subclass relation is a *requirement* on that specific type which is `Floating` to also be (in) `Num` i.e. to implement `Num`'s methods as well as the ones from `Floating`.

So yes, a (specific, concrete) `Floating` type can also be treated as a `Num` type.

On the other side of things, `sqrt` produces the same type as its input type, so it will be the same concrete `Floating` type. But `floor` expects a `RealFrac` type.

Observe

```
> :t floor            ----------
floor :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b

> :t sqrt . fromIntegral            ----------
sqrt . fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Floating c) => a -> c

> :t floor . sqrt            ----------  ----------
floor . sqrt :: (Integral c, RealFrac b, Floating b) => b -> c

> :i Floating
class Fractional a => Floating a where
  ....
instance Floating Float
instance Floating Double

> :i RealFrac
class (Real a, Fractional a) => RealFrac a where
  ....
instance RealFrac Float
instance RealFrac Double
```

So the concrete type produced (and thus, accepted) by that `sqrt` call must be (in) `RealFrac` as well as `Floating`.

Since it is not observed from outside of that application chain it could be any compliant type, and is thus *ambiguous*; but *type defaulting* kicks in and selects `Double`, unless you've changed the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

> So `sqrt` takes something of `Floating` type but it is supplied with `Num`.

**No**. The `fromIntegral` guarantees that it can convert *any* number with a type that is a member of the `Integral` typeclass to *any* `Num` type, not to *a* `Num` type.

Since `sqrt` needs an number that is a member of the `Floating` typeclass, for that specific case, `fromIntegral` will specialy to return something of a type that is a member of the `Floating` typeclass.

Comment: Can you provide some sources so I can read more about it ? Is this behavior caused by the `forall` thing ?

Comment: @Red_Black: yes, as is specified in the Haskell report (https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/5.00/docs/set/universal-quantification.html) says that all type variables are impliclty *universally* quantified at the *outer* level. You can make use of `forall` to quantify and a different level (or use `forall` at the outer level, but that is not necessary).